# Why is this webpage non-scrollable?

Tags: html, css

Recently, after adding more and more information to [this page](http://elijahandandrew.com/repo/depictions/ReachApp/#recentchanges), I have noticed that its not possible to scroll, it just cuts off depending on the browser resolution.

Any help would be dearly appreciated.

Comment: Because it has `overflow:hidden` in the body?

Answer (score 4):

Adding `overflow:auto;` to both `body` and `#recentchanges` should *fix* it. However, the real problem is that jQuery is adding these attributes, which suggests you should look at your CSS code and figure out the root of the problem. It seems you copy-pasted some code, so you might want to go through the file `jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css` and remove instances of `overflow:hidden` from there.

Answer (score 1):

```
.ui-mobile-viewport-transitioning,.ui-mobile-viewport-transitioning .ui-page {
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow:hidden; <= THIS IS THE CAUSE.
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

remove

```
   .ui-mobile-viewport-transitioning, .ui-mobile-viewport-transitioning .ui-page {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      overflow: hidden;/*remove*/
      width: 100%;
}
```

from js library 
or adding 
`overflow:auto` to body

Answer (score 1):

To add scroll to page use overflow-x:scroll for bottom scroll and overflow-y:scroll for vertical scroll and overflow:scroll for both